# Exception : org.hibernate.SessionException: Session was already closed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am developing application using java + spring + hibernate + oracle. when i add the below property in my **dispatcher-servlet.xml** file.

```
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</prop>
```

It throws exception as below :

```
org.hibernate.SessionException: Session was already closed
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.close(SessionImpl.java:302)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.closeSession(SessionFactoryUtils.java:791)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.closeSessionOrRegisterDeferredClose(SessionFactoryUtils.java:777)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion(HibernateTransactionManager.java:737)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.cleanupAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:1011)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:804)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy354.getMenu4Priv(Unknown Source)
at com.itzcash.easy.reports.controller.SalesDistributionReportController.searchCustomerProfile(SalesDistributionReportController.java:261)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:208)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:181)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

if i remove this property no exception is occurred.

My code is like below :

```
  @Service
    Class ABCServiceImpl 
{
    @Transactional
    void methodA()
    {
       // called the method in DAOImpl package -- methodB().
    }

}

@Repository
Class ABCDAOImpl
{
    @Autowired
    SessionFectory s;

    void methodB()
    {
      // hibernate operatoion
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide code snippet where is is throwing this exception.

Comment: Are you doing hibernate operations inside transaction?If not do all the operation on session within transaction,as 
`hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session` will close session after transaction.

Comment: Can u just show little bit of code that what u doing. ?

Comment: In ServiceImpl package : i have use the @Transactional and from that i called the DAOImpl Package. and performed all transactional operation. then how i resolved this ?

Comment: @Krishna I added some basic structure of my code.

Comment: @KevalTrivedi but that is not the thing if i can see your transaction of data that how u performing that and if session is already close then u can not do other thing till u open it again.

Comment: @Krishna give me some hint that if session is close then i open it again.

Comment: @KevalTrivedi Simple as that SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().openSession();

Comment: @Krishna there is no method like SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().openSession()  
openSession() method is not there.

Comment: @KevalTrivedi do one thing make new object of Session ses = s.getcurrentSession(); and then after that make ses.openSession(); try to debug that code and if still facing issue then remove that auto close session property from the xml file. :)

Answer (score 6):

1. Try to close the connection manually. and
2. use .openSession(); method to open session instead of .getCurrentSession(); no exception comes.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you cant call `close()` twice on a `Session`, the second time you call the `close()` method, it will throw that Exception.

By setting `auto_close` you are implicitly closing the session after you use it, so the solution would be removing the `close()` methods in your code, or just remove that `auto_close` config and close the sessions manually after using them.

Comment: i am not using close() method in my code. i am using the @Autowired concept of sessionFectory so no need to close it.
i am using sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().

Comment: ah, then the problem is that getCurrentSession is getting you the previous session which was closed automatically because of that, so trying to use it again (even though its closed) gives you that too. But all this it pretty much guessing since we dont see any code we could analyze.

Comment: @KevalTrivedi simple thing is to open that sesstion again ;)

Comment: I want to close the connection implicitly. because of when i fetching the large amount of data from database it takes long time. if i implicitly close the connection after the transaction. it gives me fast response.

Answer (score 1):

If this flag is set to true then session will be automatically closed during the after completion phase of the transaction. Agree with Edward on what you are trying to implicitly close the connection throwing that Exception.

Comment: I want to close the connection implicitly. because of when i fetching the large amount of data from database it takes long time. if i implicitly close the connection after the transaction. it gives me fast response.